# When/where to pull in global settings?

Tags: react-admin

My application has a number of settings that are used in most of my different pages and I am currently loading these settings in each different page every time. Since these are global settings I'd like to pull them all in at once around login time, put them in a react context, and then grab them from context as required in various components.

I have done a few quick tests, but have run into various issues like my context trying to pull in settings before login is complete (which fails due to no token). I put the settings call in my dashboard component, which works except the user can navigate around the dashboard and miss the settings call.

I feel like there must be a simple recommended pattern that I'm not thinking about. Let me know any thoughts!

Comment: You're loading the settings from the server, is that correct? If it's the case, I suggest you update your authProvider to also fetch the settings, and tore them somewhere in localStorage. That way, you can grab them from anywhere. If the user isn't logged, the, the settings won't be available, but if the user is logged the settings should always be available?.

Comment: Thank you, Francois, that makes sense. In one of my tests, I was trying to find some way to get the data out of the authProvider and into a React Context, which I realized is never really going to work since the authProvider is itself is well outside of React. I did not even think about the fact that localStorage is right there waiting for me! I will consider this as a new option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my current 'solution' in case it is useful. I will look into using localStorage as per François' suggestion, but before localStorage had even occurred to me I found this method of getting my data into a React Context. I'm not exactly certain why my method is working so well since it feels a little outside expected react-admin behavior, but here it is!

First I made a React Context (PackageFieldsContext) and wrapped my Admin component. I placed a custom component as one of the Admin children - this component (PackageFieldsDataFetcher) has no content, has no accessible path, and renders nothing. It fetches data with a custom hook and puts the data into context.

Admin with provider and data fetcher component:

```
    <PackageFieldsProvider >
      <Admin 
        authProvider={authProvider} 
        dataProvider={dataProvider} 
        dashboard={Dashboard}
        layout={MyLayout}
        customRoutes={customRoutes}
      >
        <Resource 
          name="Packages" 
          list={PackageList}
        />
        <PackageFieldsDataFetcher />
      </Admin>         
    </PackageFieldsProvider>
```

Component:

```
  const PackageFieldsDataFetcher = () => {
    const { setPackageFields } = useContext(PackageFieldsContext); //get useState setter from context
    const [ fieldsLoading, returnedFields, ] = useGetPackageFields(); // retrieve data with my custom hook

    useEffect(() => {
      if(!fieldsLoading) {
        setPackageFields(returnedFields);
      }
    }, [fieldsLoading]); //when fields are loaded, set them in context
  
    return (
      <>
      </>
    );
 }
```

This feels slightly hacky; I know that even if my custom component had something to render, the Admin component would not render it because it's not a resource. But, Admin still seems to let everything else in the component work.

This component does get 'mounted' before login so it always tries to reach out to pull the data before login happens, and so I always get a 401 when loading the page. I'm sure I can use either useAuthenticated or useAuthState hooks to stop this 401 error, but we'll see.. There could be some other issues I'm not seeing yet as well